# Container-managed transactions and Java persistence API

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, transactions

I have some questions regarding container-managed transactions in JPA. For example, I have JSF page with managed bean, which calls a session bean's method:

```java
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TestController {
    @EJB
    private TestBean bean;

    public String action() {
        bean.check();
        return null;
    }
}

@Stateful
@LocalBean
public class TestBean {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public Object check() {
        return em.createQuery("SELECT u from User u WHERE u.id = 1").getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

Do I understand correctly, that if `check()` method is invoked within the same transaction, then `EntityManagers` will have the same persistence context and the method will return the same `Object` over and over?

If there will be several requests to action() method of the controller, will `EntityManagers` have different persistence contexts for each request?
Does it depend on the type of session bean: stateful or stateless?

What if I change the scope of the controller to `@SessionScoped` and create several requests from the same session?

In general, are there any rules that define when a container creates new transactions? Does it depend on the container type (I'm using Glassfish)?